# Jest not covered the function inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I want to test a function that fetch something from server, it looks like this :

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function Component1() {

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchSomeData();
    }, [])

    const fetchSomeData = async () =>{
        console.log('fetchSomeData')
       

    }
    return <div>Component1</div>;
}

export default Component1;
```

and test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Component1 from './Component1.js';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Name of the group', () => {
    it('should ', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Component1 />);
        expect(wrapper.exists());
        
    });
});
```

[![picture1][1]][1]

### but the test is not covered 'fetchSomeData', any one knows why?

I referred this answer :
[test restapi inside useeffect in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368499/test-restapi-inside-useeffect-in-jest)
try to mock a fn and call it , but I got this:

[image]

Comment: You should not use async await in useEffect, just call fetchSomeData without await

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hook Warnings for async function in useEffect: useEffect function must return a cleanup function or nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret)

Comment: thanks, I have changed the code to avoid use await inside a useEffect, but my problem is about I need to 100% covered my code test with jest. but it seems not covered the red part of my code.

Comment: You should NOT return data in the callback of `setTimeout`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928846/get-return-value-from-settimeout